# Using asp:content markup more than once in the masterpage

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET and want to have an asp:content control for the page title, but I want that value to be used for the  tag and for a page header. When I tried to do this with two  tags with the same id, it complained that I couldn't have two tags with the same id. Is there a way to achieve this with contentplaceholders, and if not what would be the easiest way to use a single parameter to the masterpage twice in one page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title is actually an attribute on content pages, so you do something like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/default.master" Title="My Content Title" %>
```

on the content page. To get that into a header, on the master page just render the page title:

```
<h1><%= this.Page.Title %></h3>
```

Comment: Is there a way to generalize this if I need to do something similar for another attribute?

Comment: Not sure what you mean...maybe you could edit to include a code sample of what you'd *like* to be able to do?

Comment: I think I figured out what I was not very clearly trying to ask.
I was having trouble getting this.Title to work, I think it's supposed to be this.Page.Title

Comment: Oy - you're absolutely right. In a master page, you should reference this.Page. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see that someone has just provided a (far) better answer to this specific problem. You could use the solution below if you have a master page that has the same content in multiple places (excluding the title).

The best solution I can come up with is the following:

Add an `asp:Label` for the page title and another one for the second position you want the text to appear (use two different id's, for example: `pageTitle` and `sameTitle`)

Add a method to your master page:

```
public void SetPageTitle(string title)
{
    pageTitle.Text = title;
    sameTitle.Text = title;
}
```

On your content page, call the master page method. If your content page has a master page, it has a property called `Master`. You can now call the `SetPageTitle` method from your content page `PageLoad` method:

```
((MyMasterPage) Master).SetPageTitle("My content page");
```

You can also use the `MasterType` directive in your master page, check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx) for more info. This way you get a strongly-typed `Master` property that you do not have to cast:

```
Master.SetPageTitle("My content page");
```

Regards,
Ronald

Answer (score 0):

Also, master pages can have different content tags (with different Id's) which is good if you want pages to potentially alter various parts of the page.